# How to setup multinode corda network in lab

Tags: corda

I followed the documentation from docs.corda.net to setup 3 node dev corda network on a single machine. 
My goal is to setup multinode production level corda network that involves multiple physical machines. Can someone please help me how can I achieve this?

I want to learn about the corda network capabilities, its different configuration modes etc etc.

I've already setup 3 node dev corda network on a single machine

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches with which you can achieve the above

1. Using the network bootstrapper , refer : https://docs.corda.net/network-bootstrapper.html
2. Using the Network Map Service

For a production level it is preferable to use the network map service as you can manage the nodes dynamically. This is not possible with the networkbootstrapper as the nodes informations are shared within the nodes during the boostrapping which cannot be changed

For NetworkMap Service you can refer Cordite NetwokMapService.